# how to sum up two cells in an html table using java script

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display the sum of "unit price" and "quantity" under the "total" which is disabled. And once that is done I want to allow the user to calculate the grand total and display that for which I have provided a button but I do not exactly know how to use DOM to do that. I have not added a script tag yet in the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Book Ordering System</title>
        <style>
            table, tr, td {
                border: grey;
                border-style: ridge;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-width: 2px;
            }

            thead {
                background-color: skyblue;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            tr {
                height: 30px
            }

            td {
                padding: 3px 5px;              
            }    

            tfoot {
                background-color: skyblue;
                text-align: right;
            }

            input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
            input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
               -webkit-appearance: none;
            }

            tr.footer {
                height: 50px;
            }

            .unit_price, .quantity, .total {
                width: 80px;
                text-align: right;
            }

            .total {
                background-color: silver;   
            }

            .grand_total {
                background-color: silver;
                width: 150px;
                height: 30px;
                border: 5px 7px 7px 45px;
                font-size: larger;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: right;
            }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Book Ordering System</h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>No.</td>
                    <td>Book Title</td>
                    <td>Author</td>
                    <td>Category</td>
                    <td>Unit Price</td>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                    <td>Total</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input class="book_title" type="text" name="title" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
                <td><input class="author_name" type="text" name="author" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="category">
                        <option selected disabled hidden>Please choose the category...</option>
                        <option value="">Business</option>
                        <option value="">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="">Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="">Technology</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input class="unit_price" type="number" name="unit_price" maxlength="20" value="0.00"></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" type="number" name="quantity" maxlength="20" value="0"></td>
                <td><input class="total" type="number" name="total" maxlength="20" value="0.00" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><input class="book_title" type="text" name="title" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
                <td><input class="author_name" type="text" name="author" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="category">
                        <option selected disabled hidden>Please choose the category...</option>
                        <option value="">Business</option>
                        <option value="">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="">Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="">Technology</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input class="unit_price" type="number" name="unit_price" maxlength="20" value="0.00"></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" type="number" name="quantity" maxlength="20" value="0"></td>
                <td><input class="total" type="number" name="total" maxlength="20" value="0.00" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><input class="book_title" type="text" name="title" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
                <td><input class="author_name" type="text" name="author" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="category">
                        <option selected disabled hidden>Please choose the category...</option>
                        <option value="">Business</option>
                        <option value="">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="">Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                </td>
                <td><input class="unit_price" type="number" name="unit_price" maxlength="20" value="0.00"></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" type="number" name="quantity" maxlength="20" value="0"></td>
                <td><input class="total" type="number" name="total" maxlength="20" value="0.00" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td><input class="book_title" type="text" name="title" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
                <td><input class="author_name" type="text" name="author" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="category">
                        <option selected disabled hidden>Please choose the category...</option>
                        <option value="">Business</option>
                        <option value="">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="">Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="">Technology</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input class="unit_price" type="number" name="unit_price" maxlength="20" value="0.00"></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" type="number" name="quantity" maxlength="20" value="0"></td>
                <td><input class="total" type="number" name="total" maxlength="20" value="0.00" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td><input class="book_title" type="text" name="title" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
                <td><input class="author_name" type="text" name="author" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="category">
                        <option selected disabled hidden>Please choose the category...</option>
                        <option value="">Business</option>
                        <option value="">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="">Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="">Technology</option>        
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input class="unit_price" type="number" name="unit_price" maxlength="20" value="0.00"></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" type="number" name="quantity" maxlength="20" value="0"> </td>
                <td><input class="total" type="number" name="total" maxlength="20" value="0.00" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr class="footer">
                <td colspan="5"><button>Calculate Grand Total Price</button></td>
                <td colspan="2"><input class="grand_total" type="number" name="grand_total" maxlength="20" value="0.00" disabled></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: what have you already tried ?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) Show CODE. Not PICTURES of code

Comment: @ashishsingh I have not added the script tag to the code yet as I do not know how to calculate these.

Comment: There are so many Q&A on adding input values in HTML/JavaScript; you should really first do your research.

Comment: @mplungjan thank you very much for the help! I have one more question, how can I make the calculate grand total button work so that it only gets calculated when i press it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version

I added ID to the tbody

To only show the grand total when clicking, I made the calc return the total

```js
const calc = () => {
  let total = 0;
  [...document.querySelectorAll("#tb tr")].forEach(function(row) { // all rows
    // not super important to cast to number when you have multiplication, but we do it anyway
    let subTotal = +row.querySelector("[name=unit_price]").value *
      +row.querySelector("[name=quantity]").value;
    row.querySelector("[name=total]").value = subTotal.toFixed(2);
    total += subTotal;
  });
  // document.querySelector("[name=grand_total]").value = total.toFixed(2);
  return total.toFixed(2); // so you can click your button
};
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("tb").addEventListener("change", calc);
  document.getElementById("showTotal").addEventListener("click",function() {
    document.querySelector("[name=grand_total]").value = calc();
  });  
});
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: grey;
  border-style: ridge;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-width: 2px;
}

thead {
  background-color: skyblue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

tr {
  height: 30px
}

td {
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

tfoot {
  background-color: skyblue;
  text-align: right;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

tr.footer {
  height: 50px;
}

.unit_price,
.quantity,
.total {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: right;
}

.total {
  background-color: silver;
}

.grand_total {
  background-color: silver;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 5px 7px 7px 45px;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>Book Ordering System</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>No.</td>
      <td>Book Title</td>
      <td>Author</td>
      <td>Category</td>
      <td>Unit Price</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Total</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input class="book_title" type="text" name="title" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
      <td><input class="author_name" type="text" name="author" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
      <td>
        <select name="category">
          <option selected disabled hidden>Please choose the category...</option>
          <option value="">Business</option>
          <option value="">Fiction</option>
          <option value="">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input class="unit_price" type="number" name="unit_price" maxlength="20" value="0.00"></td>
      <td><input class="quantity" type="number" name="quantity" maxlength="20" value="0"></td>
      <td><input class="total" type="number" name="total" maxlength="20" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><input class="book_title" type="text" name="title" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
      <td><input class="author_name" type="text" name="author" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
      <td>
        <select name="category">
          <option selected disabled hidden>Please choose the category...</option>
          <option value="">Business</option>
          <option value="">Fiction</option>
          <option value="">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input class="unit_price" type="number" name="unit_price" maxlength="20" value="0.00"></td>
      <td><input class="quantity" type="number" name="quantity" maxlength="20" value="0"></td>
      <td><input class="total" type="number" name="total" maxlength="20" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><input class="book_title" type="text" name="title" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
      <td><input class="author_name" type="text" name="author" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
      <td>
        <select name="category">
          <option selected disabled hidden>Please choose the category...</option>
          <option value="">Business</option>
          <option value="">Fiction</option>
          <option value="">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input class="unit_price" type="number" name="unit_price" maxlength="20" value="0.00"></td>
      <td><input class="quantity" type="number" name="quantity" maxlength="20" value="0"></td>
      <td><input class="total" type="number" name="total" maxlength="20" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td><input class="book_title" type="text" name="title" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
      <td><input class="author_name" type="text" name="author" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
      <td>
        <select name="category">
          <option selected disabled hidden>Please choose the category...</option>
          <option value="">Business</option>
          <option value="">Fiction</option>
          <option value="">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input class="unit_price" type="number" name="unit_price" maxlength="20" value="0.00"></td>
      <td><input class="quantity" type="number" name="quantity" maxlength="20" value="0"></td>
      <td><input class="total" type="number" name="total" maxlength="20" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td><input class="book_title" type="text" name="title" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
      <td><input class="author_name" type="text" name="author" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
      <td>
        <select name="category">
          <option selected disabled hidden>Please choose the category...</option>
          <option value="">Business</option>
          <option value="">Fiction</option>
          <option value="">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input class="unit_price" type="number" name="unit_price" maxlength="20" value="0.00"></td>
      <td><input class="quantity" type="number" name="quantity" maxlength="20" value="0"> </td>
      <td><input class="total" type="number" name="total" maxlength="20" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="footer">
      <td colspan="5"><button id="showTotal">Calculate Grand Total Price</button></td>
      <td colspan="2"><input class="grand_total" type="number" name="grand_total" maxlength="20" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Once again thank you very much for your help, And Can I know how to make it such that when I press the "Calculate Grand Total" button only then it calculates and displays the grand total? instead of automatically getting it done.

Comment: See update. But why must they click? It is more elegant when they do not have to click

Comment: Yes I totally agree its more elegant without having to press the button itself but its actually sort of a requirement, And I got it now thanks a lot for your help sir.